# Why would the circle next to username turn orange right after logging on to Gmail chat?

Tags: gmail, google-talk

My friend just got onto Gmail and the circle next to their name turned orange not green, yet they just got on and in the past it always turned green first. Is this a flaw or some sort of maneuver?

Answer (score 2):

Orange circle means idle state, that means no activity. Even if you have open Gmail tab in a browser with other tabs and you are not active in Gmail tab more than 5 min, the chat circle will go from green to orange.